# Access Ionic 3 page outside

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building an PWA application using Ionic 3 (without Cordova plugin), and now I need to implement a password recovery feature. To do that I need to send an email to user with a link. When the user clicks the link I need to redirect him to a page with a token to recover that password.

I have tried to implement this feature using IonPage segment, as you can see below.

```
@IonicPage({
  segment: 'token/:token'  
})
```

Calling the following URL: http://localhost:8100/#/token/mytoken I'm redirected to root page (login).

How can I do that?

Comment: Yeah Ionic 3's navigation system would not support what you have here. In Ionic 4 using Angular router you can do exactly what you want I think easier. In this PWA www.morphistic.app - we implemented the forgot password page but then redirect is just a simple html page. No ionic.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko do you are using ionic v3 ? Does deeplinks can solve this problem ?

Comment: Yes Ionic 3. And no deep links do not really help as they only partially help navigation across the app using browser url / location.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Ok.. so, my best option is create a new page only to do that outside my app, is it ?

Comment: This is what we did yes. You can use Ionic 4 vanilla js approach if you want to stick to the same style for your webapp